# How to generate a rotationally symmetric function with a 1d array in python?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, signal-processing

I have a 1D array and I want to rotate it around its centre to generate a symmetric 2D array. How can I do it?
For example, I define a 1D window array via scipy and now I want to generate its 2D version which has rotation symmetry. However, the result of `numpy.outer` doesn't have rotation symmetry.

```
from scipy.signal import windows
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
exp1 = windows.get_window(('exponential', None, 5), 60)
exp2d = np.sqrt(np.outer(exp1, exp1))
plt.imshow(exp2d)
```

[image]

I realize that if the 1D window has a analytical form, it is simple to do it. However, is there some general method for an arbitrary 1D array (function) without analytical form?

Comment: I realize that if the 1D window has a analytical form, it is simple to do it. However, is there some general method for an arbitrary 1D array (function) without analytical form?

Comment: The crux your question was in your comment, so I moved that into the question. The short answer is, "no", there is no general way to do this. For example, when defined radially, you will need to know the evaluation of the function at non-integer values, and there's no generalized way to do this. For example, at the point `(1,1)` the radius is `sqrt(2)`, and the value at `sqrt(2)` is not in your 1D data. You could, eg, interpolate, but that's not the solution you'd always want to take, so it's not really a "general" method.

Comment: Tom is right that interpolation is imperfect. But, if we're talking about smooth functions like the exponential window in your example, interpolation could work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. Here is a possible approach:

1. Generate a "radius" image like this, where at each point, the pixel value is its distance from the center:

   [image: radius image]
2. Evaluate `f(radius)`, where `f` is any 1D function. For instance:

   [image]

   Alternatively, if you have a 1D array and not a function, interpolate it for instance with [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) like `f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)`.

Comment: Do you have the code for the first figure @Pascal Getreuer?

Comment: @stars83clouds it's easy with np.meshgrid. Look in the [np.meshgrid documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) for the example with the line `zz = np.sqrt(xx**2 + yy**2)`, which makes a similar "radius" image.